# Word or phrase for the ability to learn and also understand

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What word(s) combine the act of learning and subsequent understanding of a lesson or concept? It may be related to *comprehension*.

It is used in the present-tense in a sentence like this:

> Let the same energy surround your soul with the same positivity,
>   (blank), fulfillment and reinforcement of the ideas we've shared
>   together.

Comment: Surround your soul with the same positive energy, comprehension, knowledge,  fulfillment and reinforcement of the ideas we've shared.

Comment: Consider "discernment" (*acuteness of judgment and understanding*).

Answer (score 1):

A word which *broadly* means what you want but fits very well in your example sentence is ***enlightenment***.

> Let the same energy surround your soul with the same positivity,
>   ***enlightenment***, fulfillment and reinforcement of the ideas we've shared together.

MW:

> **[enlightenment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enlightenment)**
>   *noun*
>   **1** : the act or means of enlightening : **the state of being *enlightened***
>
> His comments failed to provide enlightenment.
>
> **[enlightened](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enlightened)**
>   *adjective*
>   **2** : based on full comprehension of the problems involved
>
> an enlightened approach to prison reform

Answer (score 0):

**Learnability**, not to be confused by the term in software testing (which means that a software is easily learned by people). According to an [article on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/learnability-most-important-employability-skill-lynette-daly):

> *"***Learnability** *is the desire and the capability to develop new in demand skills quickly in order to meet the demands of a changing employability landscape and marketplace."* [1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/learnability-most-important-employability-skill-lynette-daly)

According to the [Wikipedia article on this type of learnability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learnability):

> *"In a labor market increasingly dictated by skills, individuals need to develop and demonstrate* **learnability** — *the desire and ability to quickly grow and adapt one’s skill set — in order to stay relevant and succeed."* [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learnability)

It's also used by respected organisations, for example in this article [by Harvard Business Review](https://hbr.org/2016/07/its-the-companys-job-to-help-employees-learn):

> "*As academic reviews have pointed out, people’s employability – their ability to gain and maintain a desired job – no longer depends on what they already know, but on what they are likely to learn.*
>
> *In other words, higher career security is a function of employability, and that in turn depends on* **learnability***."* [3](https://hbr.org/2016/07/its-the-companys-job-to-help-employees-learn)

#### Attribution

[1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/learnability-most-important-employability-skill-lynette-daly) L. Daly. "Learnability The Most Important Employability Skill?" LinkedIn. November 01, 2016. Accessed March 23, 2018. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/learnability-most-important-employability-skill-lynette-daly.

[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learnability) "Learnability." Wikipedia. February 28, 2018. Accessed March 23, 2018. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learnability.

[3](https://hbr.org/2016/07/its-the-companys-job-to-help-employees-learn) T. Chamorro-Premuzic and M. Swan. "If You're Not Helping Employees Learn, You're Not Doing Your Job." Harvard Business Review. October 05, 2016. Accessed March 23, 2018. https://hbr.org/2016/07/its-the-companys-job-to-help-employees-learn.

Answer (score 0):

to **discern** [free dictionary](https://www.freethesaurus.com/discern)

> 1. (tr) to recognize or perceive clearly
> 2. to recognize or perceive (differences)

Answer (score 0):

Simply using "understanding" would work well within the context. Understanding is (from the Oxford dictionary) "The ability to understand something; comprehension."